# FFT reordering phase

Tags: c, algorithm, fft

I've got some code for you guys. 
This is the first step of the splitting algorithm for the Fast Fourier Transform.

What the algorithm should do is reorder the array such that every element on the input will be displaced in the "binary mirrored" position of the output.

For example, the element X[4] will be in position X[1], since the mirrored representation of 100 is 001.

Till here, everything is clear. However, the algorithm that does such reordering is not. Atleast I have a hard time understanding.

What does the second, inner loop do?

```
// N is the length of the array
// p is the number of bits needed to represent the index

for(int n=0; n<N; n++) {

   int j=0; 
   int m=n;
   for(int i=0; i<p; i++) {
     j = 2∗j + m%2; m = m/2;
   }

   if ( j>n) { 
     complex<double> h;
     h = X[j]; 
     X[j] = X[n]; 
     X[n] = h;
   }

}
```

Comment: You have this marked as C, but use complex<double>, a C++ type.  Which way are we going with this one?

Comment: That's a particularly disgusting way to bit-reverse the index

Comment: Unsure about the question here: `1`, `2`, and `4` when  "binarly mirrored" all become `1`.

Comment: @WeatherVane different kind of mirroring, the index is said to have `p` bits which are mirrored around the middle of the `p` bits (not around the middle of the input)

Comment: Michael Dorgan, I hope you will forgive me, I'm really sorry for that.

Comment: 2  is 010, which becomes 010, which is 2.
1 is 001, which becomes 100, which is 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of an integer as being a sequence of bits.

- `j = 2j` this pops the bit on the left and pushes zero into the right
- `m % 2` this obtains the right bit
- `m = m / 2` pops the bit on the right and pushes a copy of the leftmost bit on the left
- `j + x` sets the rightmost bit of `j` to `x`, assuming that bit is currently zero and that `x` is `0` or `1`

so all this is doing is popping bits off of the right of `m` and pushing them onto the right of `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration, we multiply `j` by 2 (which is the same as shifting left by 1), then add the parity of `m`. Then we do integer division of `m` by two (which is the same as shifting right by 1). `m` starts with the value of `n`. So we are essentially reversing the bits in `n`, and storing it in `j`.